# Jquery less than equal to logical issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, logical-operators

I have 4 input fields:

1. credit
2. balance
3. amount
4. receipt balance and its amount.

All are array input types.

**Objective:**

1. If any values in credit amount is greater than its particular array value of credit balance then flag is set to `1`
2. Similarly, if receipt amount is greater than its balance then flag1 is set to `1`

**Problem:** When both values equal also its taking flag as `1`

```
$('#check_bala').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var inps = document.getElementsByName('credit_bala[]');
    var inps1 = document.getElementsByName('apply_amount[]');
    var inps2 = document.getElementsByName('balance_rece[]');
    var inps3 = document.getElementsByName('apply_amount1[]');
    var flag = 0;
    var flag1 = 0;
    for(i=0;i<inps.length;i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<inps1.length;j++)
      {
      if(inps[i].value <= inps1[j].value)
      {
        flag=1;
      }
      }
    }
      for(i1=0;i1<inps2.length;i1++)
    {
      for(j1=0;j1<inps3.length;j1++)
      {
      if(inps2[i1].value <= inps3[j1].value)
      {
        flag1=1;
      }
      }
    }
    console.log(flag);
    console.log(flag1);
    if(flag== 0 && flag1== 0)
    {
      console.log("its done");
//$("#apply_form").submit();
    }
    else
    {
      alert("Applied Amount is greater than your balance.Try again!");
    }
  });
```

Comment: Can you change <= to <

Comment: i need to check for less than or equal bro

Comment: Are the values strings that need to be converted to numbers?

Comment: @JasonB Javascript will take care of typecasting automatically, so it can't be that

Comment: u mean by parseInt

Comment: Yes parseInt or parseFloat. @AbhishekAnand, console.log ( "23" < "100" ); results in false because 23 is alphabetically "greater than" 100 since 2 comes after 1. JS doesn't know it should typecast if they are both strings.

Comment: But its not taken in string. I have checked with parseInt too

Comment: Currently you're comparing _every_ credit balance to _every_ apply amount  and setting the flag if _any_ credit balance is less than or equal to _any_ apply amount. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: what do you want when both value is same ?  'done' or 'not done' ?

Comment: @KavyaShree No debate, parse the inputs before going further.

Comment: what do you want if credit_balance is 100 and applied_amout is 100 ? , flag 0 or flag 1 ?

Comment: Yes wht @JLRishe told is right

Comment: I tried with parseInt too

Comment: In my case only 4 items, credit amount and its balance , receipt amount and its balance., if credit amount is greater than the balance or any receipt amount greater than balance then alert will show

Comment: Do not try, do parse the input before debugging, and include the parsing into your question >:-(

Comment: @KavyaShree Just to make perfectly clear: If you had credit_bala = [20, 30] and apply_amount = [15, 25] would you want the page to show an error, or not? With your current logic it would because 20 < 25.

Comment: in this case it wont show error because 20<15 and 30<25

Comment: can u suggest me solution for this? please reply

Answer (score 0):

One big problem here is that you're not parsing the numbers, but another is that your looping is all wrong. You are comparing *every* credit balance to *every* apply amount instead of just comparing values within the same row. You need to process the values as rows of values.

Also, for some reason you are using `<=` when it seems clear that you should be using `<`.

This should work:

```js
$('#check_bala').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var credits = document.getElementsByName('credit_bala[]');
  var applys1 = document.getElementsByName('apply_amount[]');
  var reces = document.getElementsByName('balance_rece[]');
  var applys2 = document.getElementsByName('apply_amount1[]');
  var flag1 = false;
  var flag2 = false;

  var rowCount1 = Math.min(credits.length, applys1.length)
  for (var i = 0; i < rowCount1; i += 1) {
    if (Number(credits[i].value) < Number(applys1[i].value)) {
      flag1 = true;
    }
  }

  var rowCount2 = Math.min(reces.length, applys2.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < rowCount2; i += 1) {
    if (Number(reces[i].value) < Number(applys2[i].value)) {
      flag2 = true;
    }
  }

  console.log(flag1);
  console.log(flag2);
  if (flag1 || flag2) {
    alert("Applied Amount is greater than your balance.Try again!");
  } else {
    console.log("it's done");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Credit Balance</th>
      <th>Apply Amount</th>
      <th>Balance Rec.</th>
      <th>Apply Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" name="credit_bala[]" min="0" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="apply_amount[]" min="0" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="balance_rece[]" min="0" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="apply_amount1[]" min="0" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="number" name="credit_bala[]" min="0" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="apply_amount[]" min="0" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="balance_rece[]" min="0" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="apply_amount1[]" min="0" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="check_bala" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: if both amount and balance is equal too its done case only. how can you check that case?

Comment: @KavyaShree I don't understand what you're asking. Can you give an example?